# Partition moving resizing and separate home partition, is disk space from / also used?

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted, home-directory

Greetings I am a Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS 32-bit user and there are 3 mount partitions and hence 3 mount points on my system: one for root directory, one for /home and one for swap. My question is since root directory is the parent directory of home does something stored in the home directory invade space in both root and home partitions?

Furthermore, I have too less space remaining on my root partition and likewise for the home partition. I would like extend the root partition into space before it (to the left as seen in `Gparted`), and extend the home partition into the space before it after moving the root partition to the left a bit. Is it too risky to be done?

Thanks for your suggestions

Output of `sudo parted --list`

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MK5061GS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      32.3kB  109MB   109MB   primary   fat16           diag
 2      109MB   21.1GB  21.0GB  primary   ntfs            boot
 3      21.1GB  155GB   134GB   primary   ntfs
 4      155GB   500GB   345GB   extended                  lba
 5      155GB   409GB   253GB   logical   ntfs
 6      445GB   474GB   29.1GB  logical   ext4
 8      474GB   496GB   21.5GB  logical   ext4
 7      496GB   500GB   4295MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Output of `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6        27G   25G  839M  97% /
udev            2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           392M  932K  391M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G   18M  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda5       236G  145G   92G  62% /media/DATA
/dev/sda8        20G   18G  1.4G  93% /home
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, your disk usage for your / does not include your home directory.

Have you thought about putting your home in the empty space instead of sliding everything over?  Either way, GParted won't be able to move/resize a file system while it's mounted and being used.  You can use your Ubuntu live drive or disc for that if you've got one.

The more direct route would be to boot friendly-recovery, and use parted to adjust your partition table, and then use resize2fs to adjust filesystems.

Anyways, you now need to match your universally unique identifiers (UUID) for your changed filesystems (see by running 'sudo blkid') to your filesystem table entries in the file '/etc/fstab' .. notice the UUIDs, and mount points.

Next, update your boot image with 'sudo update-initramfs -u', and then run 'sudo update-grub' to be able to boot that image.

Comment: Yeah I just freed up the space before root partition with Windows disk management tool so you are suggesting that I mount home to that partition and extend the root partition to the right. By the way what do you mean by `friendly-recovery` is it some sort of program? How can I use parted to adjust the partition table and then resize2fs without messing my data?

Comment: I did it through Gparted with graphical user interface and it handled these by itself thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: well good. =)  home partition relocated and / stretched over? btw, when I said friendly recovery I was talking about your 'recovery' option at your grub menu.

Comment: Well I looked at the logs of Gparted and saw the command `resize2fs` invoked by the program so I did not do anything extra apart from first moving the `/` root partition to the left then expanding it. Afterwards I proceeding with allocating the remaining space for the home partition hopefully everything was flawless.